# Augmenting training data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm working through an exercise for augmenting training data and then testing it through the artificial neural network. The idea is to test the accuracy as more data is added to the training set.

I'm using the mnist dataset.

This how I am rotating the image:

```
def rotate_image(inputs, degree):

    ## create rotated variations
    # rotated anticlockwise by x degrees
    inputs_plusx_img = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(inputs.reshape(28,28), degree, cval=0.01, order=1, reshape=False)
    new_inputs1 = inputs_plusx_img.reshape(784)
    # rotated clockwise by x degrees
    inputs_minusx_img = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(inputs.reshape(28,28), -degree, cval=0.01, order=1, reshape=False)
    new_inputs2 = inputs_minusx_img.reshape(784)

    return (new_inputs1, new_inputs2)

degree = 10
df = pd.read_csv(train_file) 
#print(df.head())
idx = 100
instance = df.iloc[idx:(idx+1), 1:].values
#print(instance.reshape(28,28))
new_image1, new_image2 = rotate_image(instance, degree)
# show rotated image
image_array = np.asfarray(new_image1).flatten().reshape((28,28))
print(new_image1)
# print the grid in grey scale
plt.imshow(image_array, cmap='Greys', interpolation='None')
```

Now what I'm not sure about is how to add the new image to the training data set and then add it to the ANN class.

This is my neural network:

```
class neuralNetwork:
    """Artificial Neural Network classifier.

    Parameters
    ------------
    lr : float
      Learning rate (between 0.0 and 1.0)
    ep : int
      Number of epochs
    bs : int
      Size of the training batch to be used when calculating the gradient descent. 
      batch_size = 1 standard gradient descent
      batch_size > 1 stochastic gradient descent 

    inodes : int
      Number of input nodes which is normally the number of features in an instance.
    hnodes : int
      Number of hidden nodes in the net.
    onodes : int
      Number of output nodes in the net.


    Attributes
    -----------
    wih : 2d-array
      Input2Hidden node weights after fitting 
    who : 2d-array
      Hidden2Output node weights after fitting 
    E : list
      Sum-of-squares error value in each epoch.

    Results : list
      Target and predicted class labels for the test data.

    Functions
    ---------
    activation_function : float (between 1 and -1)
        implments the sigmoid function which squashes the node input

    """

    def __init__(self, inputnodes=784, hiddennodes=200, outputnodes=10, learningrate=0.1, batch_size=1, epochs=10):
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        #two weight matrices, wih (input to hidden layer) and who (hidden layer to output)
        #a weight on link from node i to node j is w_ij


        #Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution centered around 0.
        #numpy.random.normal(loc to centre gaussian=0.0, scale=1, size=dimensions of the array we want) 
        #scale is usually set to the standard deviation which is related to the number of incoming links i.e. 
        #1/sqrt(num of incoming inputs). we use pow to raise it to the power of -0.5.
        #We have set 0 as the centre of the guassian dist.
        # size is set to the dimensions of the number of hnodes, inodes and onodes for each weight matrix
        self.wih = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.inodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.onodes, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))

        #set the learning rate
        self.lr = learningrate

        #set the batch size
        self.bs = batch_size

        #set the number of epochs
        self.ep = epochs

        #store errors at each epoch
        self.E= []

        #store results from testing the model
        #keep track of the network performance on each test instance
        self.results= []

        #define the activation function here
        #specify the sigmoid squashing function. Here expit() provides the sigmoid function.
        #lambda is a short cut function which is executed there and then with no def (i.e. like an anonymous function)
        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

        pass

    # function to help management of batching for gradient descent
    # size of the batch is controled by self,bs
    def batch_input(self, X, y): # (self, train_inputs, targets):
        """Yield consecutive batches of the specified size from the input list."""
        for i in range(0, len(X), self.bs):
            # yield a tuple of the current batched data and labels
            yield (X[i:i + self.bs], y[i:i + self.bs])

    #train the neural net
    #note the first part is very similar to the query function because they both require the forward pass
    def train(self, train_inputs, targets_list):
    #def train(self, train_inputs):
        """Training the neural net. 
           This includes the forward pass ; error computation; 
           backprop of the error ; calculation of gradients and updating the weights.

            Parameters
            ----------
            train_inputs : {array-like}, shape = [n_instances, n_features]
            Training vectors, where n_instances is the number of training instances and
            n_features is the number of features.
            Note this contains all features including the class feature which is in first position

            Returns
            -------
            self : object
        """

        for e in range(self.ep):
            print("Training epoch#: ", e)
            sum_error = 0.0   
            for (batchX, batchY) in self.batch_input(train_inputs, targets_list):
                #creating variables to store the gradients   
                delta_who = 0
                delta_wih = 0

                # iterate through the inputs sent in
                for inputs, targets in zip(batchX, batchY):
                    #convert  inputs list to 2d array
                    inputs = np.array(inputs,  ndmin=2).T
                    targets = np.array(targets, ndmin=2).T

                    #calculate signals into hidden layer
                    hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
                    #calculate the signals emerging from the hidden layer
                    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

                    #calculate signals into final output layer
                    final_inputs=np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
                    #calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
                    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

                    #to calculate the error we need to compute the element wise diff between target and actual
                    output_errors = targets - final_outputs
                    #Next distribute the error to the hidden layer such that hidden layer error
                    #is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden nodes
                    hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

                    ## for each instance accumilate the gradients from each instance
                    ## delta_who are the gradients between hidden and output weights
                    ## delta_wih are the gradients between input and hidden weights
                    delta_who += np.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)), np.transpose(hidden_outputs))
                    delta_wih += np.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)), np.transpose(inputs))

                    sum_error += np.dot(output_errors.T, output_errors)#this is the sum of squared error accumilated over each batced instance

                pass #instance

                # update the weights by multiplying the gradient with the learning rate
                # note that the deltas are divided by batch size to obtain the average gradient according to the given batch
                # obviously if batch size = 1 then we simply end up dividing by 1 since each instance forms a singleton batch
                self.who += self.lr * (delta_who / self.bs)
                self.wih += self.lr * (delta_wih / self.bs)
            pass # batch
            self.E.append(np.asfarray(sum_error).flatten())
            print("errors (SSE): ", self.E[-1])
        pass # epoch

    #query the neural net
    def query(self, inputs_list):
        #convert inputs_list to a 2d array
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T 

        #propogate input into hidden layer. This is the start of the forward pass
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)

        #squash the content in the hidden node using the sigmoid function (value between 1, -1)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        #propagate into output layer and the apply the squashing sigmoid function
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)

        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        return final_outputs


    #iterate through all the test data to calculate model accuracy
    def test(self, test_inputs, test_targets):
        self.results = []

        #go through each test instances
        for inputs, target in zip(test_inputs, test_targets):
            #query the network with test inputs
            #note this returns 10 output values ; of which the index of the highest value
            # is the networks predicted class label
            outputs = self.query(inputs)
            #get the target which has 0.99 as highest value corresponding to the actual class
            target_label = np.argmax(target)
            #get the index of the highest output node as this corresponds to the predicted class
            predict_label = np.argmax(outputs) #this is the class predicted by the ANN

            self.results.append([predict_label, target_label])
            pass
        pass
        self.results = np.asfarray(self.results) # flatten results to avoid nested arrays
```

Functions to per process data and then train network:

```
def preprocess_data(Xy):
    X=[]
    y=[]
    for instance in Xy:
        # split the record by the ',' commas
        all_values = instance.split(',')
        # scale and shift the inputs
        inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
        # create the target output values (all 0.01, except the desired label which is 0.99)
        targets = np.zeros(output_nodes) + 0.01
        # all_values[0] is the target label for this record
        targets[int(all_values[0])] = 0.99
        X.insert(len(X), inputs)
        y.insert(len(y), targets)
    pass
    return(X,y)
pass  

mini_training_data = np.random.choice(train_data_list, 60000, replace = False)
print("Percentage of training data used:", (len(mini_training_data)/len(train_data_list)) * 100)

X_train, y_train = preprocess_data(mini_training_data)
X_test, y_test = preprocess_data(test_data_list)


  n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs)

n.train(X_train, y_train)    

n.test(X_test, y_test)
#print network performance as an accuracy metric
correct = 0 # number of predictions that were correct

#iteratre through each tested instance and accumilate number of correct predictions
for result in n.results:
    if (result[0] == result[1]):
            correct += 1
    pass
pass

# print the accuracy on test set
print ("Test set accuracy% = ", (100 * correct / len(n.results)))
```

Comment: Where is the code where you call the method `train`?  You probably just want to append these rotated images to your `train_inputs`.

Comment: hi, sorry, added now

Comment: @Dan, sorry to bother you again but do you have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: You can add your training data to train_data_list & run the same ANN again. If this doesn't resolve , can you please elaborate what you are actually looking at??

Comment: **(1)** I would change `rotate_image` to only output 1 image (drop the `-degree` rotation **(2)** make a wrapper around `rotate_image` that generates `n` images rotated at a random angle between `threshold` and `-threshold`. It should output an array with shape `(784, n)`. **(3)** inside your `preprocess_data` loop, call this new wrapper function (maybe with a random `n`) and append the out to your `x` list. So instead of `X.insert(len(X), inputs)` I would do `X.append(inputs)` and `X.append(augmented_images)`. Don't forget to append `target` `n` times as well to match.

Comment: Another note, instead of `X.append()` (which I;m pretty sure will be better than `X.insert`, you could preallocate a numpy array since you know upfront what the final size of `X` will be. I would guess this would be more efficient. i.e. something like `X = np.zeros(784, 60000)` *before* your loop and then instead of `X.insert(len(X), inputs)` you would have `X[row, :] = inputs` and you can get `row` by defining you loop as `for row, instance in Xy:`.

Comment: sorry I'm new to Python, would you be able to show how this is done?

Comment: the task states:   when using this function to insert new training instances you must ensure that the class label is inserted to the corresponding targets array, n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs) n.train(X_train, y_train) not really sure what is means to insert the class label? Can this be explained please?